# Linq2SQL: SubmitChanges covered by a transaction?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, transactions

```
MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext();

// do a lot of insert, deletes and updates

context.SubmitChanges();
```

Will all SQL genereated and executed by SubmitChanged() be covered by a transaction? How do I make sure it's covered by a transaction?

Updated:

The reason why I asking it that I having a weird bug where I suspect a transaction hasn't been used.

The procedure is about 500 inserts and a final update on one record. Sometimes the update (and perhaps a few of the insert...) isn't registered in the database.

(SQL Transactions isn't shown in my debug output?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542525/transactionscope-vs-transaction-in-linq2sql

See the answer with the most votes. The accepted answer doesn't tell the whole story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is, and the whole thing will roll back if it fails

[How to: Submit Changes to the Database (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399378.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

If you want everything to happen within a transaction use a Transaction Scope

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx

Comment: Linq2Sql will create a transaction for you, no need to throw the confusion of TransactionScope in the mix.

Comment: +1. TransactionScope simplifies code a bit as it doesn't require a try catch block for a Rollback.

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly creating a TransactionScope is only needed when you are invoking SubmitChanges multiple times and want all of the invokations to be included in one single transaction.