# Multiple SubmitChanges and transaction rollback using Linq To SQL

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, transactionscope

I'm using TransactionScope to submit data in Linq to SQL. My question is, if I use multiple SubmitChanges in the same scope, will all scope roll back in case of an error or just the changes made after the last SubmitChanges? For example:

```
using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext())
    {
        try
        {
            //do some insert
            db.SubmitChanges();

            //do some updates
            db.SubmitChanges();

            trans.Complete();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}
```

If update SubmitChanges throws an exception, will the insert SubmitChanges roll back too?

Comment: Check out this similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542525/transactionscope-vs-transaction-in-linq2sql - in particular, the first answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ALL changes will roll back, not just the one from the last SubmitChanges().

You will often need to use this pattern when you have data that depends on other data -- like if you need to create an object and get it's auto-generated ID in order to do something else (though L2SQL supports that with one SubmitChanges call in most scenarios by just creating the object, but I digress...).