# How to handle transaction in WCF Service with LINQ

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am using WCF Service which performs database transaction. I am finding a way to rollback when any operation fails.

```
  public void UpdateFirstTable()
            {
                //Linq query to update table1
            }

        public void UpdateSecondTable()
        {
            //Linq query to update table2
        }
```

if an exception occus while performing any operation in UpdateFirstTable() & UpdateSecondTable() changes made should be rolled back. How to achieve this?

Comment: LINQ2SQL and EF both support TransactionScopes - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542525/transactionscope-vs-transaction-in-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx#Y1900