# Difference Between Transaction and TransactionScope

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, transactions, transactionscope

I am developing an application which communicates with an SQL Server 2005 database to execute some stored procedures. My client demands that all transactions be managed on the C# side and not by SQL Server, and so I am using `System.Transactions.TransactionScope` when accessing the database. However, I have just seen the `System.Transactions.Transaction` datatype, and I am confused... What are the main pros/cons of each type? Which one should I use?

Please note that I must also use Enterprise Library's Data Access Application Block.

Comment: Looks like a repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542525/transactionscope-vs-transaction-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224689/transactions-in-net

Comment: `My client demands that ...` .. why? What is it that the client *really* wants / is afraid of? It's almost certain that they don't *actually* want that directly - they want something else and have decided that forcing the Transaction into C# is the way to do it. "E.g. I read somewhere that SQL Transactions aren't reliable"... etc.

I doubt that you'll be able to resolve their underlying fears / desires unless you understand what they really want.

Comment: a simple answer to your question could be "we have a programmer that only understands one of them on staff".  Or more relevantly, they want all of the code modifying the database in the same place so it's easier to work on.  These "why why why" comments are incredibly unnecessary and irrelevant.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From msdn :

> The TransactionScope class provides a
>   simple way to mark a block of code as
>   participating in a transaction,
>   **without requiring you to interact with the transaction itself**. A
>   transaction scope can select and
>   manage the ambient transaction
>   automatically. Due to its ease of use
>   and efficiency, it is recommended that
>   you use the TransactionScope class
>   when developing a transaction
>   application. **When you instantiate
>   TransactionScope, the transaction
>   manager determines which transaction
>   to participate in**. Once determined,
>   the scope always participates in that
>   transaction. The decision is based on
>   two factors: whether an ambient
>   transaction is present and the value
>   of the TransactionScopeOption
>   parameter in the constructor. The
>   ambient transaction is the transaction
>   within which your code executes. You
>   can obtain a reference to the ambient
>   transaction by calling the static
>   Current property of the Transaction
>   class.

You can read more about that here :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152(v=vs.90).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.90).aspx

Great (a bit old) article about transaction in .NET 2.0

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973865.aspx