# Entity framework 4.5 and 5 and serial list processing possible without stored procedure?

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency

My C# application uses EF and calls min() on an int column to get the 'next' number in a sequence of numbers from a database table. The database table already has the next X numbers ready to go and my EF code just needs to get the 'next' one and after getting this number, the code then deletes that entry so the next request gets the following one etc. With one instance of the application all is fine, but with multiple users this leads to concurrency issues. Is there a design pattern for getting this next min() value in a serial fashion for all users, without resorting to a stored procedure? I'm using a mix of EF4.5 and EF5.

Thanks, Pete

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can add an timestamp type column into your table and on Entity Framework property window set the concurrency mode to Fixed. 
Doing that you enable optimistic concurrency check on the table. If there is another data context tries to interrupt your update, it will generate an excepton.

Check this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/05/20/tip-19-how-to-use-optimistic-concurrency-in-the-entity-framework.aspx?Redirected=true

Alternatively, you can use a TransactionScope object on your select/update logic. You can simply wrap around your code logic with a TransactionScope logic and everything within the scope will be enforced by the transaction.

Check this link for more information:
[TransactionScope vs Transaction in LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542525/transactionscope-vs-transaction-in-linq-to-sql)